# ReactJS: useState for array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with onChange, in the onChange function I need to save values.

```
const [choosenVar, setChoosenVar] = useState([
    {
      posto1: { name: '', value: '' },
    },
    {
      posto2: { name: '', value: '' },
    },
    {
      posto3: { name: '', value: '' },
    },
    {
      posto4: { name: '', value: '' },
    },
    {
      posto5: { name: '', value: '' },
    },
    {
      posto6: { name: '', value: '' },
    },
  ]);


  const onChange = event => {
    const { name, value, id } = event.target;
    // setchoosenVar({ ...choosenVar, [`posto${id}.nome`]: value });
    const newArr = [...choosenVar];

  };
```

Now my problem is for every "id" on event.target I should save the name and value in posto"id", How can I do??

Example:

```
const onChange = event => {
    const { name, value, id } = event.target;
    // name: "Application", value: "appSett", id: "1"
    // in this case I should take: choosenVar.posto1 and set choosenVar.posto1.name = name, choosenVar.posto1.value= value.
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Always make a copy of array state variables first using `...` (spread operator).

`findIndex()` and update the object at the found index. Using `Object.keys()` we are getting all the keys of the object, since we are only concerned about the first one we check for it.

You might need spread again to make a copy of the object so you do not mutate state somehow

```
  const onChange = event => {
    const { name, value, id } = event.target;
    const newArr = [...choosenVar];

    let foundIndex = newArr.findIndex(x => { return Object.keys(x)[0] === 
   `posto${id}` });

    let copyObject = {...(newArr[foundIndex][`posto${id}`]) };

    newArr[foundIndex] = { [`posto${id}`] : copyObject };
     setChoosenVar(newArr );
  };
```

Note: The above assumes that there are no empty objects. And the Id you are looking for exists.

Would like to add that their might be a better way to store your state. An array with elements like might be easier to handle

```
   {
      posto: { id : 1, name: '', value: '' },
    }
```

Comment: So i should create an array with elements like this:  `{
      posto: { id : 1, name: '', value: '' },
    }, 
{
      posto: { id : 2, name: '', value: '' },
    }`

Comment: Yes. In the longer run that should be a better idea. The solution above is for your current implementation though

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
    const { name, value, id } = event.target;
    setChoosenVar({
      ...choosenVar,
      ...{`posto${id}`:value}
    })
```